# xui.js swipe plugin - how to get element id

Tags: cordova, xui

i'm using xui in a photegap project as it's going pretty well except that, when using the swipe plugin, I can't find a way to get the tapped element id attribute.

Can anyone help me on thie one?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The callback that you pass into the `swipe` method gets passed the touch event object as the first parameter.

As such, you can check out the [Touch Event documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/TouchEvent), especially the `touches` array of `Touch` objects; these [`Touch` objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Touch) have a `target` attribute that gives you a direct reference to the element that the touch event started on.